# Noether's theorem, dimension of the group of symmetry and dimension of conserved quantity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem, degrees-of-freedom

I previously asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange about the relation between $\bigwedge^2(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\text{SO}(n)$. See [this link to the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965281/equality-of-dimension-of-bigwedge2-bbb-rn-and-textson). I noticed that they have equal dimensions, that I think they are related. It happens that the question I have in mind may actually be related to physics. So I post the question here.

First, I noticed the following things. Hopefully my understandings are correct:

> Time translational symmetry is described by $\Bbb R$, which is a one-dimensional Lie group. The corresponding conserved quantity (energy) lies in a one-dimensional vector space.
>
> Spatial translational symmetry is described by $\Bbb R^3$, which is a three-dimensional Lie group. The corresponding conserved quantity (momentum) lies in a three-dimensional vector space.
>
> Rotational symmetry is described by $\text{SO}(3)$, which is a three-dimensional Lie group. The corresponding conserved quantity (angular momentum) lies in a three-dimensional vector space.

The reason I have thought that $\bigwedge^2(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\text{SO}(n)$ are related is actually about a hypothetical angular momentum in a hypothetical $n$-dimensional space. If there is an $n$-dimensional space, and there is a Lagrangian which is invariant under the group action of $\text{SO}(n)$, I guess that the quantity $r\wedge p$ (angular momentum) of a particle is conserved along the allowed paths, where $r$ is the position of the particle from the origin, and $p$ is the momentum. The quantity $r\wedge p$ lies in the vector space $\bigwedge^2(\Bbb R^n)$, which has the same dimension as $\text{SO}(n)$.

From the above observations, I have made the following conjecture:

> If a continuous symmetry of the Lagrangian is given by a Lie group of dimension $n$, then the corresponding conserved quantity lies in an $n$-dimensional vector space.

Is it really the case?

Comment: They are related simply because $\Lambda^2(\mathbb R^n)$, when seen as vector space of antisymmetric real $n\times n$ matrices and equipped with the standard commutator, is the Lie algebra of $SO(n)$. So if $R\in SO(n)$ since $SO(n)$ is compact, we have  $R = e^{A}$ for some $A \in \Lambda^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: The answer to your final question is YES, but it is independent from the case of $SO(n)$ and $\Lambda^2(\mathbb R^n)$. It is just the application of Noether theorem for every one-parameter subgroup of the Lie group (assuming that the representation of the group in terms of symmetries is faithful).

Comment: @ValterMoretti we can also exponentiate A in $\bigwedge^2(\Bbb R^n)$ to group elements in the indefinite signature, noncompact case of $SO(p,q)$, can't we?

Comment: No, we cannot, because the Lie algebra of $S(p,q)$ is not made of anti symmetric n x n  matrices. If you exponentiate that A you find an element of $SO(n)$.

Comment: But does it have to? , the metric signature seems to make sure antisymmetric elements of $\bigwedge^2(\Bbb R^n)$ are mapped to the elements of the so(p, q) Lie algebra.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector#Spacetime_rotations

Comment: $\eta A+ A^t\eta=0$ with $\eta = diag(-1,...,-1,1,...,1)$ respectively p an q times is $so(p,q)$. Instead, $A$ is antisymmetric if $A+A^t=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I used A meaning an element of the exterior algebra isomorphic to $so(p,q)$, not $so(n)$.

Comment: i.e.:the exterior square not seen as a vector space of antisymmetric matrices but as elements of an antisymmetric tensor in a Lorentzian metric space.